# Babel changes name of injected angularjs services

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, babeljs

I have a controller which simplified looks very much like this.

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService) {
    let ctrl = this;
    ctrl.myService = myService;
});
```

Problem is when I run it through babel in grunt it ends up looking like this

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, _myService) {
    let ctrl = this;
    ctrl.myService = _myService;
});
```

And that does not work because I don't have a service called `_myService`.
Is there anything I can do with babel to prevent this from happening?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using TypeScript modules or namespaces?

Comment: I am not using TypeScript, don't know about namespaces

Comment: Are you just using ES6 and using Babel to transpile to ES5?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Maybe try looking into annotation libraries that preserve the dependency injection variables: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate

Comment: Thank I will look into that

Comment: Regardless of the way the service is annotated, [strict DI mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp#usage) should be used to never let DI errors accidentally appear in a situation like that.

Comment: @estus is right, you should also enable Strict DI Mode regardless

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
  let ctrl = this;
  ctrl.myService = myService;
}]);
```

This inline annotation means that minification will now work.

Comment: I am not trying to minify, I am simply trying to convert from ES6 to ES6 by using grunt and babel

Comment: @ØrnulfArntsen DI annotation isn't specific to minification. This makes DI to not rely on function signatures and avoid situations like that.